# Send GET request directly after object from previous GET request is available?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rest, http

When initializing the MatchComponent, i want to do 
1. Get request to get Match object (Match object has a member playerIDs)
2. Get request to get Players (based on playerIDs in the Match object)

Due to the asynchronous communication my code below does not work. How can I handle this?

match.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-match',
  templateUrl: './match.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./match.component.css']
})
export class MatchComponent implements OnInit {

  match: Match;
  players: Player[];

  constructor(private matchService: MatchService,
              private playerService: PlayerService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadData();
  }

  loadData(): void {
    const matchID = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.getMatchByUniqueID(matchID); // first get request
    this.match.playerIDs.forEach(id => {
      this.getPlayerByUniqueID(id); // get requests that can only work when the match object is set correctly
    });
  }

  // ---------------------------------------------------------
  // HTTP ----------------------------------------------------
  // ---------------------------------------------------------
  getMatchByUniqueID(id: number): void {
    this.matchService.getMatch(id)
      .subscribe(match => {
        if (match.status === 'SUCCESS') {
          this.match = Object.setPrototypeOf(match.data, Match.prototype);
        }
      });
  }

  getPlayerByUniqueID(id: number): void {
    this.playerService.getPlayer(id)
      .subscribe(player => {
        if (player.status === 'SUCCESS') {
          this.players.push(Object.setPrototypeOf(player.data, Player.prototype));
        }
      });
  }

  updateMatch(match: Match): void {
    console.log('update');
    this.matchService.updateMatch(match)
      .subscribe(() => this.match);
  }

}
```

match.ts

```js
export class Match {
    //...
    playerIDs: number[]; /// IDs of players playing this match
    //...
}
```

match.service.ts

```
import { Match } from './match';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { HttpResponseType } from './http.response';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MatchService {

  private matchesURL = 'http://localhost:8080/matches';

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getMatch(id: number): Observable<HttpResponseType<Match>> {
    const url = `${this.matchesURL}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<HttpResponseType<Match>>(url)
      .pipe(
        // tap(_ => this.log(`fetched hero id=${id}`)),
        catchError(this.handleError<HttpResponseType<Match>>(`getUser id=${id}`))
      );
  }

  /** PUT: update the match on the server */
  updateMatch(match: Match): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(this.matchesURL + '/' + match.uniqueID, match, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      // tap(_ => this.log(`updated user id=${user.id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Match>('updateMatch'))
    );
  }

  // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your needs right, you want to make Request 2 using data from Request 1.

This can easily be done with RxJs `switchMap` operator.

All you need is

```
// First you pipe to the source observable which GETs the data you need
this.firstRequest$.pipe(
  // you may apply a filter() pipe which will pass data forth if it returns true
  // like filter(res => res.status === 'SUCCESS')

  // Then you call method which receives some needed data for second request
  // and returns observable of 2nd request
  switchMap(res => this.secondRequest(res.id))
).subscribe(res => {
  // process the result of 2nd request
});
```

Here is a small example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-47hmp1?devtoolsheight=60

```
import { of } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, filter, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

// Here we get a source observable
function getFirstObservable() {
  return of({
    data: {
      id: 3
    },
    status: 'SUCCESS',
  });
}

// This is a second source which requires some data to receive first
function getSecondObservable(id: number) {
  return of('I was called with id ' + id);
}

getFirstObservable().pipe(
  // filter allows emmited values to pass only when resolves to true
  filter(response => response.status === 'SUCCESS'),
  // Allows us to subsribe to the observabe returned by callback when
  // source observable emits value
  switchMap(response => getSecondObservable(response.data.id))
).subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
  // handle result

  // here goes the result of a second observable when and only when second observable
  // emmits value
}, err => {
  // handle error logic
})
```

Comment: Hi, I think that would solve my problem without implementing an anti pattern like nested subscriptions. But it seems that I am not experienced enough, to apply that to my code. I am already failing to implement the filter. I think it would be quite close to your provided example in the end, but currently i have problems. Would it be possible to you to provide a code snippet that fits to my example? I am sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: @user3255080 check it out

Answer (score 0):

Only make the subsequent, dependent requests once the first call completes - using the Observable returned by the http request to do this. This allows you to chain your requests in the required order.

```
  loadData(): void {
    const matchID = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.getMatchByUniqueID(matchID).subscribe(match => { //subscribe to the http observable
        if (match.status === 'SUCCESS') {
          this.match = Object.setPrototypeOf(match.data, Match.prototype);
        }
        this.match.playerIDs.forEach(id => {
        this.getPlayerByUniqueID(id); // get requests that can only work when the match object is set correctly
      });
  }

  // ---------------------------------------------------------
  // HTTP ----------------------------------------------------
  // ---------------------------------------------------------
  getMatchByUniqueID(id: number): Observable { // <-- note we are returning the observable here
    return this.matchService.getMatch(id);
  }

  getPlayerByUniqueID(id: number): void {
    this.playerService.getPlayer(id)
      .subscribe(player => {
        if (player.status === 'SUCCESS') {
          this.players.push(Object.setPrototypeOf(player.data, Player.prototype));
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Nested subscriptions is an antipattern

https://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/fixing-rxjs-anti-patterns

Comment: Thanks @maury844 - I wasn't aware of that!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your **loadData** and **getMatchByUniqueID** methods in match.component.ts to get the correct answer. You should call **getPlayerByUniqueID** method after getting all the data from your first api call.

```
loadData(): void {
  const matchID = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  this.getMatchByUniqueID(matchID);          
}

getMatchByUniqueID(id: number): void {
  this.matchService.getMatch(id)
    .subscribe(match => {
      if (match.status === 'SUCCESS') {
        this.match = Object.setPrototypeOf(match.data, Match.prototype);

        // call the playerByUniqueId from here
        this.match.playerIDs.forEach(id => {
          this.getPlayerByUniqueID(id);
        });
      }
    });
}
```